# Check if an object is empty in my db

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop

i am trying to check if a field in my prestashop db is empty. In case is empty i want to display a default message otherwise i want to display whatever field contains. In my product.tpl file i have use these 4 versions but nothing works:

```
{if !$product->available_now}
{l s = 'Default Message'}
{else}
{$product->available_now}
{/if}

---

{if empty($product->available_now)}
{l s = 'Default Message'}
{else}
{$product->available_now}
{/if}

---
{if $product->available_now === NULL}
{l s = 'Default Message'}
{else}
{$product->available_now}
{/if}

---

{if $product->available_now == ""}
{l s = 'Default Message'}
{else}
{$product->available_now}
{/if}
```

whats the correct way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
{if ! isset($product->available_now)}
Its not Set
{/if}
```

Try it

Comment: the problem solved..the whole code was in a div tha the js automatically made hidden the specific class..thanks for your answer Gaurav..